# Problem understanding the keyframes in css

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have the following keyframes, by which i want to animate logo of windows:

```
.box {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
}

#box1 {
  #background-color: red;
  animation: box1 4s 1s infinite;
}

#box2 {
  #background-color: lightgreen;
  animation: box2 4s 1s infinite;

}

@keyframes box2 {
   0% {
    background-color: #1b2028;
  }
  25% {
    background-color:  #1b2028;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #1b2028;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  100% {
    background-color: #1b2028;
  }

}

@keyframes box1 {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: red;
  100% {
    background-color: #1b2028;
  }
}
```

The problem however is only one of the keyframe is working. ie only keyframe with name box2 works and when i place keyframe of box1 on top it works, why is that so. Can someone please provide me a good understanding of keyframes?. The link to codepen is: https://codepen.io/theredcap/pen/qvJdJa?editors=1100

Comment: hope this will make more sense for your understanding.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check your css with a linter?
[CSS lint](http://csslint.net/) found 4 errors and 6 warnings.

Fix following errors.

- Expected RBRACE at line 54, col 9.
- Expected RBRACE at line 72, col 9.
- Expected RBRACE at line 90, col 9.
- Expected RBRACE at line 107, col 9.

You are missing a closing `}` :)

Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/foxfabi/pen/oVaePr

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you for taking your time to look through it :D